# Why is Iron Ore so rare at Y Coordinate equal to 5?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am playing vanilla and I am using the branching method to mine (y=5), but it is really hard to find iron ore. Has this changed in recent updates?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

y=5 is extremely inefficient for mining pretty much everything. Generally, the lowest you want to mine is around y12 if you're looking for a number of things like diamonds, Redstone and so on.

To answer the question in the title, the reason why Iron is so bad to mine at y5 is that this the point that bedrock starts to appear as well as being within the range of lava. From the below graph you'll see that around y5 everything begins to drop off and the rarity of ores increases.

Nothing has actually changed in terms of ore generation and rarity with 1.15.2.

From a statistical standpoint, you can see the likelihood of ore from the below graph along with additional information to specific ores.

[image]
[image]

Comment: by looking at the graph it seems like y5 have the same stats as y12 or y50, the only tru thing about iron is, as found in the wiki, it appears below y63, still I found way less ay y5 :/, anyways, the lava is a thing to consider, you are right. where do you get this graph?

Comment: y12 is the best simply because it captures so much at the top level such as lap, redstone and diamonds - also iron drops around y5 because bedrock enters the pool - the graph is from the wiki

Comment: thanks!, I will put this as accepted answer :)